# Fill a hole with a new vertex and then triangulate

Tags: mesh

Hi have a mesh where each internal vertex has 6 neighbours. However there's a hole in the mesh I'd like to fill by creating a new vertex and then join the 6 closest neighbours, see picture below. Any suggestion how I can do that?

Basically I want to pass from a situation where I have the stuff in the red circle to a connectivity like the one highlighted in green.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Fill and Poke**

[image]

- Select the perimeter vertices (or edges) of the hole.
- Fill with an ngon <kbd>F</kbd>
- [Poke](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#poke-faces) the ngon <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

To start off, select the perimeter of your hole with the edge select tool and move your cursor to it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and selecting "Cursor to Active".

[image]

Next you should select a similar set of triangles that will fill the hole:

[image]

Next press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the faces and move them somewhere so you don't have overlapping vertices:

[image]

[image]

Next, while you have your replacement faces selected, and your 3D cursor in where it should be, Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again and select "Selection to cursor (Offset)".

Finally, after you have everything in place, select the whole mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the Specials menu and "Remove doubles".

[image]

If it doesn't remove any vertices, try turning up the "Merge Distance" value a little bit.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: After you select the edges  fill (F) will make an ngon face  which can be [poked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#poke-faces)

Comment: True, there are faster ways, but this method can be really easily scaled and has methods that can be used in other situations.